# EvaluateXPath Empty String Set

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-nifi

I'm using `EvaluateXPath` in NiFi to add the value of `ActivityTypeCode` as an attribute. It is being routed to the matched relationship, but when I look at the attributes it says empty string set.

I have the destination set to flowfile-attribute, the return type is a string, validate dtd is true, and then I added a field called `ReportType` (what I want to name the attribute) with the XPath expression `string(//Activity[1]/ActivityTypeCode/text())`. I've tried with and without the `string()` wrapper and it still returns an empty string set. I tested this XPath expression on [this](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) site and it works without issue.

What am I doing wrong?

**XML**

```
<Base>
  <Activity>
    <ActionTypeCode>R</ActionTypeCode>
    <ActivityID>123456</ActivityID>
    <ActivityName>Suspicious Activity</ActivityName>
    <ActivityTypeCode>SA</ActivityTypeCode>
  </Activity>
</Base>
```

**ETA: the issue was I had validate dtd on but I didn't have anything to validate**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your xpath expression to "//*[local-name()='ActivityTypeCode']" and see if that gets you anything.